# Get position of svg element in svg with multiple transforms

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a SVG-document that contains a circle. I would like to place an absolutely positioned html-element on top of this circle. The circle contains a cx and cy and there are several transforms on parent elements. How can I translate the position inside the SVG to the coordinate space of the parent html-element (normal pixels)?

The SVG is generated by a program, so I will have little control over it, meaning that I will need a general solution that can handle any number of transforms on parent element.

I'm not using d3 or any similar library, so I'm looking for a way to solve this using plain JavaScript. This is a simplified example of my problem:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #box {
            background-color: greenyellow;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <svg width="1274.2554" height="692.35712" id="svg">
            <g id="viewport" transform="matrix(0.655937472561484,0,0,0.655937472561484,162.2578890186666,57.23719435833714)">
                <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-5.49584,-171.51931)">
                    <g id="elem" transform="translate(34.862286,232.62127)">
                        <circle id="center" cx="19.952429" cy="19.90885" style="fill:#ffcc33" r="20"></circle>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <div id="box" ></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function positionBoxAtCenter() {
            var box = document.getElementById('box');
            var center = document.getElementById(('center'));
            // TODO: get x, y from 'center' so that 'box' can be placed on top of center
            var x = 0, y = 0;
            box.setAttribute('style', 'top: ' + y + 'px; left: ' + x + 'px');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p9pf56sz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```
var pos = center.getBoundingClientRect();
```

You can get the center of the circle:

```
var x = pos.left + pos.width/2, y = pos.top + pos.height/2;
```

Here is the demo:

```js
function positionBoxAtCenter() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    var center = document.getElementById(('center'));
    var pos = center.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = pos.left + pos.width/2, y = pos.top + pos.height/2;
    box.setAttribute('style', 'top: ' + y + 'px; left: ' + x + 'px');
}

positionBoxAtCenter();
```

```css
#box {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <svg width="1274.2554" height="692.35712" id="svg">
            <g id="viewport" transform="matrix(0.655937472561484,0,0,0.655937472561484,162.2578890186666,57.23719435833714)">
                <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-5.49584,-171.51931)">
                    <g id="elem" transform="translate(34.862286,232.62127)">
                        <circle id="center" cx="19.952429" cy="19.90885" style="fill:#ffcc33" r="20"></circle>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <div id="box" ></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

However, as you can see in the demo, you are moving the top/left corner of the rectangle (its origin)  to the center of the circle. So, you'll have to calculate the center of the rectangle as well (and subtract its difference to the origin).